# Difference between a gradient vector and a gradient vector field

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

Consider a function

$$f(x,y,z,w) = x^2 + 2y +3 \sin z +4w^3 $$

Then the gradient vector is given by

$$\nabla f = [f_x, f_y, f_z, f_w] = [2x, 2, 3 \cos z, 12w^2]$$

But, is it the same as a gradient vector field, or gradient vector field is a set of other vectors defined by $f$

i.e., $\vec{f} = 2x \hat{i} + 2 \hat{j} + 3 \cos z \hat{k} + 12w^2 \hat{l}$ ?

Comment: By the first notation in brackets, you mean a column vector?

Comment: @ConfusedHuman Yeah.

Comment: Yes, they are same, but you cannot graphically represent any of them, because it's in four dimension. Your basis vector in matrix form should follow same inner product rules as the unit vectors.

Comment: You may want to use $\vec F$ or another notation for the vector and not the same as $f(x,y,z,w)$. As the vector field is the gradient of function $f(x,y,z,w)$, it is a gradient vector field.

Comment: Suppose $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable. The function $\nabla f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is a vector field on $\mathbb R^n$, and could be called a gradient vector field. If $x \in \mathbb R^n$, then $\nabla f(x)$ is a vector, called the gradient of $f$ at $x$.